# Dump with special characters in table column name

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, character-set, mysql-4

I'm taking over an old database, and while doing recovery tests from my dump I found out a table is wrongly backed up, the table definition is truncated.

Looking at the live db I've found a column name **with special character** in the name. That is the **column name** is ***Località***.

My current mysql dump produces the following:

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `contabilita_banche` (
  `ID_Banca` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `Descrizione` varchar(70) default NULL,
  `Località;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

The first problem is that the table doesn't end there, there are other fields after *Località*, so the structure dump is incomplete. Other than this the dump doesn't throw any error and the data is dumped correctly to the end.

I tried several commands, all without success:

```
mysqldump -r /tmp/cbnew2.sql --default-character-set=latin1 --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables --quick -u root -p -h host Dbname contabilita_banche
mysqldump -r /tmp/cbnew2.sql --default-character-set=utf8 --no-tablespaces --skip-lock-tables --quick -u root -p -h host Dbname contabilita_banche
```

Server version is `4.1.22-log`, client `5.5.38`. Is there any way to correctly produce the dump?

Comment: When you login to MySQL 4.1, please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE contabilita_banche\G`. Does the complete structure appear from the console ?

Comment: no, it's truncated as well, and finishes this way: `Localit?

Comment: Also, on that same server, Run `mysqldump`. --version` does it say `4.1.22` ?

Comment: mysqldump  Ver 10.9 Distrib 4.1.22, for redhat-linux-gnu (i386)

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE DATABASE DBname;`. What character set does it say ?

Comment: `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1`

Answer (score 2):

I tried renaming the table via "adminer" (php mysql manager) but even there the table name was not correct (not showing at all, to be honest). I tried renaming but of course I produced a new table column.

In the end I had to recreate the table.

I managed to get most of the schema from the `SHOW CREATE TABLE contabilita_banche\G` above. 
Then I took the dump with the data, adjusted the `CREATE TABLE` command with a utf-8 column name and restored the new dump.

Thank you very much **Rolando** for your support!

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'; may give you more clues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but sadly as I said I removed the table and I cannot test anymore